# Apache-poi Restrict the user to select only the values of drop down list

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can I make the user select only one of the values in the drop down list and not enter his own value in the excel sheet. I am using Java library Apache-POI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using HSSFWorkbook use below

```
    DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"ABC"});
    DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(programList, dvConstraint);
    dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    dataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    dataValidation.setShowPromptBox(true);

    targetSheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```

For XSSFWorkbook, use as below

```
        DataValidationHelper validationHelper=new XSSFDataValidationHelper(targetSheet);
        DataValidationConstraint constraint =validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"ABC"});
        DataValidation dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, programList);
        dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);   
        dataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
        dataValidation.setShowPromptBox(true);
        targetSheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```

Comment: Though the above solution works like a charm, it allows any value when we PASTE them. Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: That is a limitation of excel itself. When you paste values you actually replace the entire cell along with its validation rules IIRC.